# How to use the ` sr ` function in the ` scapy ` module to sniff the response packets for a custom protocol?

Tags: python, scapy

I made a custom packet layer by the module "Scapy". I want to use the `sr` function in the same module to send a UDP packet carrying this custom layer as its payload to a remote device and sniff responses from the device. Below is my code to implement for this purpose:

```
from scapy.all import *

PORTNUMBER = 8888

class MyLayer(Packet):

  name = "MyLayer"

  fields_desc = [BitField("id", 1, 16),
                 FieldLenField("len", None, length_of = "data"),
                 StrLenField("data", "", length_from = lambda pkt: pkt.len)]

  def answers(self, other):
    print(">>> Running answers of MyLayer")
    if other.__class__ == self.__class__:
      return 1
    return 0


bind_layers(UDP, MyLayer, dport = PORTNUMBER)

if __name__ == "__main__":

  src = "192.168.1.200"
  dst = "192.168.1.255"

  ipHeader = IP(src = src, dst = dst)
  udpHeader = UDP(sport = PORTNUMBER, dport = PORTNUMBER)
  myLayer = MyLayer(data = "abcd1234")
  reqPacket = ipHeader/udpHeader/myLayer

  results, _ = sr(reqPacket, 
                   timeout = 2,
                   filter = f"udp dst port {PORTNUMBER}", 
                   iface = "NIC for Test")
```

As the code above illustrates, I create the custom protocol layer called `MyLayer` which is the custom protocol I need. I  hope `sr` will use the `answers` function in the `MyLayer` class to check if a sniffed packet should be regarded as a response for the packet it sent. And to confirm that the `answers` function of `MyLayer` is called by `sr`, I print the message ">>> Running answers of MyLayer" in the beginning of the `answers` function.

However, this code does not work. The response packets from the remote device have all been disregarded by the `sr` function. And the message ">>> Running answers of MyLayer" has never been printed. I think the reason for why the code above did not work is that the received packet failed to pass check of `sr` function by the `answer` function of the `IP` layer.

Can anyone tell me if there is any way to make the `sr` function able to regard the received packets as legitimate answers for the packet it sent? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you check in wireshark for example If there is even any response?

Comment: Yes, I used wireshark to confirm that the netowrk interface card received the response packets from the remote device.

Comment: Well I tested your code in my environment and in my case it works like that: If you send by sr() function reqPacket with custom myLayer the other side should send the answer packet also with myLayer. If you binded UDP layer on dport=PORTNUMBER with your custom layer then scapy in moment of dissasembling packet will see that udp field dport=PORTNUMBER so It have to get the fields for myLayer. In my environment when I send an answer packet script just called answers function for MyLayer.

Comment: @MonteChrist0 Thanks a lot for doing the test. You are right. I just did the same test again but this time I changed the destination IP from the broadcast IP to a unicast one. And `sr` called the `answers` function of the `MyLayer` class and recognized responses from the remote device as answers. So the root cause of my problem seems to be related to the broadcast destination IP. And according to the result of my test, `bind_layers` function is not needed for `sr` to recognize the answer packets since `sr` could still recognize answer packets after I removed the line including `bind_layers`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the reply of MonteChrist0, I found that the root cause of my problem is related to the broadcast IP address of the request packet. So I add the line `conf.checkIPaddr = 0` to my code. Moreover, the `multi` parameter of the `sr` function has to be assigned the value `True` or the function will only return the request packet as the answer. Below is the code which works for me:

```
from scapy.all import *

PORTNUMBER = 8888
conf.checkIPaddr = 0

class MyLayer(Packet):

  name = "MyLayer"

  fields_desc = [BitField("id", 1, 16),
                 FieldLenField("len", None, length_of = "data"),
                 StrLenField("data", "", length_from = lambda pkt: pkt.len)]

if __name__ == "__main__":

  src = "192.168.1.200"
  dst = "192.168.1.255"

  ipHeader = IP(src = src, dst = dst)
  udpHeader = UDP(sport = PORTNUMBER, dport = PORTNUMBER)
  myLayer = MyLayer(data = "abcd1234")
  reqPacket = ipHeader/udpHeader/myLayer

  results, _ = sr(reqPacket, 
                  timeout = 2,
                  filter = f"udp dst port {PORTNUMBER}", 
                  multi = True,
                  iface = "NIC for Test")
```

I remove the lines for the `answers` function and `bind_layers` in the code above to prove that adding the line `conf.checkIPaddr = 0` alone is enough to make `sc` to recognize the response packets for the broadcast packets sent by `sr` as answers in my case.

But as MonteChrist0 pointed out earlier, if we want to implement the `answers` function of the `MyLayer` class and want it to be called by `sr`, the line for the `bind_layers` will be required. So a more complete version of the code will be as follows:

```
from scapy.all import *

PORTNUMBER = 8888
conf.checkIPaddr = 0

class MyLayer(Packet):

  name = "MyLayer"

  fields_desc = [BitField("id", 1, 16),
                 FieldLenField("len", None, length_of = "data"),
                 StrLenField("data", "", length_from = lambda pkt: pkt.len)]

  def answers(self, other):
    if other.__class__ == self.__class__:
      return 1
    return 0


bind_layers(UDP, MyLayer, dport = PORTNUMBER)

if __name__ == "__main__":

  nic = "192.168.1.200"
  dst = "192.168.1.255"

  ipHeader = IP(src = nic, dst = dst)
  udpHeader = UDP(sport = PORTNUMBER, dport = PORTNUMBER)
  myLayer = MyLayer(data = "abcd1234")
  reqPacket = ipHeader/udpHeader/myLayer

  results, _ = sr(reqPacket, 
                  timeout = 2,
                  filter = f"dst host {nic} and udp dst port {PORTNUMBER}", 
                  multi = True,
                  iface = "NIC for Test")
```

( I think it should be better to filter the request packet by the `filter` parameter of `sr` so that the request packet will not be regarded as an answer packet by `sr`. That is why I modify the condition following the `filter` parameter in the code above as well. )

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what are you trying to achieve exactly with IP2 implementation but here might be a hint for a solution. In case if your answered packet should contain MyLayer and you want function answers of that layer to be called you need to bind udp layer with MyLayer.

```
bind_layers(UDP, MyLayer, sport=PORTNUMBER, dport=PORTNUMBER)
```

that way when packet is received with that layer you could simply do

```
pkt[MyLayer].data
```

to get the field value.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually I removed `bind_layers` function in my original code to make the simplified version here. But this function didn't resolve my problem. I created the `IP2` class for I think 'sr' function shall use its `answers` function to check if the received packets can be regarded as responses for the packet it sent. And I hoped that `sr` should regard `IP` as `IP2` when it dissected received packets. But apparently I was wrong. I shall update my question to illuminate it better.